# Applying consecutive functions to a dataframe and outputting results of each into a table

Tags: r, tapply

I have a large dataframe with a similar format to below (running to ~200 compounds).

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Treatment | Compound | Proportion |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| A         | wax      | 0.095      |
| A         | alcohol  | 0.077      |
| A         | ketone   | 0.066      |
| B         | wax      | 0.067      |
| B         | alcohol  | 0.071      |
| B         | ketone   | 0.073      |
| C         | wax      | 0.051      |
| C         | alcohol  | 0.019      |
| C         | ketone   | 0.07       |
| D         | wax      | 0.033      |
| D         | alcohol  | 0.082      |
| D         | ketone   | 0.019      |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I have run anova on a linear model

```
lm(Proportion ~ Treatment)
```

for each compound using a data.table method, and generated a list of compounds for which treatment is a significant factor to subset my data to "t.df".

I'd now like to use TukeyHSD to determine which treatments are significantly different from each other for each of these compounds. I realise TukeyHSD needs an "aov" output and that I'd need to include this in my code. I think what I want is a "tapply" method to run through my list of compounds, applying the model, doing the anova then the Tukeys test and saving the format in a list of matrices.

I've been trying to play around with something like the following, but without success:

```
mytest <- function(x) { 
  model<-lm(Proportion ~ Treatment, data=t.df)
  aovmodel<-aov(model)
  tuks<-TukeyHSD(aovmodel) 
  } 
tapply((t.df[unique(t.df$Compound)]),mytest)
```

This returns the error:

```
"Error in `[.data.frame`(t.df, unique(t.df$Compound)) : 
  undefined columns selected"
```

which I think is probably the least of my problems with this piece of code.

Is there any way to extract the returned Tukey's "p adj" values for each compound tested? I'm keen to avoid doing this the long way because I have a large number of compounds in my list, and anticipate running a similar analysis with different compound names on several future datasets.

Comment: Try putting a comma after `unique(...)`.

Comment: Doing that gives another error:

"Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors"

I think "t.df$Compound" qualifies as a vector?

#editing original code from Compound.No to Compound to match example dataframe

Comment: There appear to be some issues in the example code, namely: (1) in the call to lm, shouldn't data be set to x (data=x), as it is, it looks like lm is applied to t.df in every call to mytest; (2) there is no "Compound.No" column in original data frame. Additionally, it is unclear what t.df[unique(t,

Comment: @gvrocha: The OP fixed the `Compound.No` issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intent of the `unique()` piece. Are you trying to apply it only to the unique compounds? Since there are multiple records per compound, you'd need to determine which records specifically to select.

Comment: @gvrocha: with the "t.df,unique(..." I was hoping to apply "mytest" to every value of t.df$Compound that is unique (i.e. I'd get a Tukey's output for "wax", another for "alcohol" and another for "ketone". But because in reality I have 200 compounds, I don't want to manually write a list.

Comment: You do understand that using `lm` to analyze proportions data is generally statistically invalid, right? Adding additional steps to sugarcoat an initially invalid approach does not improve validity. (You have also left out any code related to your claim that this is implementing a 'data.table method'.)

Comment: Try this: `lapply(unique(t.df$Compound), function(x, df) TukeyHSD(aov(Proportion ~ Treatment, data = df, subset = Compound == x))[[1]], df = t.df)`. However, I agree with BondedDust.

Comment: @Alex.A - Thank you, worked perfectly. BondedDust and yourself are correct, for this data set I meant to do a glm. Final code is: `lapply(unique(t.df$Compound), function(x, df) TukeyHSD(aov(glm(Proportion ~ Treatment, data = df, subset = Compound == x)))[[1]], df = t.df)`

Sorry for leaving out the data.table code. Thanks for your patience with my first post. I used the method of marbel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421396/r-data-table-loop-subset-by-factor-and-do-lm
to generate my list of significant compounds, but will have to re-visit my approach with glm for this data.

Comment: @Alex.A - I'm happy to mark this as answered if you wish to put a formal answer in.

Comment: @embee: Okay, posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Tukey HSD for each compound as you've specified, try this:

```
lapply(unique(t.df$Compound),
       function(x, df)
           TukeyHSD(aov(glm(Proportion ~ Treatment,
                            data = df,
                            subset = Compound == x)))[[1]],
       df = t.df)
```

For each unique compound, this calls `TukeyHSD()` on an ANOVA for a general linear model fit on the subset of the data corresponding to the compound. It returns a list where each element corresponds to a compound.

Comment: Thanks Alex A, works perfectly! The list format helps me to pull out the p-values too.